# Effect of breeze on a very hot day

Tags: thermodynamics

If air temperature is well above body temperature eg air temp of 50C then would a wind make the apparent temperature higher or lower.  Clearly the wind would help take away heat due to increasing evaporation of the sweating and so cool, but at the same time it would presumably be blowing air that has not been cooled down by contact with the body against the body so heating the body.

I have now been shown the q&a at [/HVAC/ Air speed and influence on human body](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/182646/hvac-air-speed-and-influence-on-human-body/182654#182654) which partly answers the question but does not have a index for windspeed.

So does anyone know a graph showing the effect of heat, wind and humidity on apparent temperature to a person?

Thanks,

Comment: I believe you can find an answer to your question [in this earlier answer of mine](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/182654/26969)

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment for some reason.
You will have to take into account the convective heat transfer coefficient of the air.  There are empirical correlations out there relating the heat transfer coefficient with velocity.

Hopefully this puts you on the right track.